# Where has the GUI gone?

Tags: asp.net, excel, export-to-excel

I have a simple ASPX page that renders a dynamically generated HTML table to Excel. It works, but as you can see from the [screenshot](http://s1104.photobucket.com/albums/h330/5arx/?action=view&current=excelproblem.png), for some reason opening the workbook results in the Excel instance having no GUI to speak of aside from the Formula bar and the worksheet tabs at the bottom. It can't be easily closed or quit either and seems to slow my workstation down too.

I'm using this code to build and export the table.

```
        runReport2();//Builds the table - this bit is fine.

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filemename=" + "FleetReport.xls");

        System.IO.StringWriter sw = new System.IO.StringWriter(); 
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        this.tblReport.RenderControl(hw);
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb1 = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        sb1.Append(sw.ToString() );
        sw = null;
        hw = null;
        Response.Write(sb1.ToString());
        sb1.Remove(0, sb1.Length);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
```

Can you suggest what I might be doing wrong? Am I doing this in a sensible way or should I be sending CSV to Excel instead?

Comment: isn't Excel simply in fullscreen ?

Comment: Nope its windowed. I can resize this minimal window by dragging the sides/corners, but cannot find the rest of the GUI.

Comment: And if you download the Excel file separately to your file system, then open from the File system, does the issue occurs ? In other words, isn't the excel file itself the source of problem, instead of your code ?

Comment: Interesting - using @AnandMohanAwasthi's solution (below) has resolved the issue with the disappearing GUI. 

I tried opening sheets generated using my old method (above) directly from Excel and couldn't replicate the problem. I *think* it is something to do with the ContentType my code was using ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment; Filename = FleetReport.xls"));
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
        this.tblReport.RenderControl(hw);
        Response.Write(sw.ToString());
        Response.End();
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much. What was I doing differently ...?

Just one thing - when I open the spreadsheet Excel says 'the file you are trying to open (myfile.xls) is in a different format than specified by the file extension" - What should the extension be?